# Automatically Updating a cell in Excel from another sheet's data, based on another cell's value

Tags: microsoft-excel

So, I have setup a drop down menu with a list of names in A1. What I want to happen, is have the Data in F34 change based on what A1 is reading. I want to have F34 update with data from another sheet.

The data would look something like this:

- Name 1 Corresponds with data on Sheet2!C6
- Name 2 Corresponds with data on Sheet2!C7
- Name 3 Corresponds with data on Sheet2!C8
- And so on.

What I tried was something like this. F34: `=IF(A1="Name 1",Sheet2!C6), (A1="NAME 2",SHEET2!C7)` And so on.

But I am not getting anywhere. Any ideas on what this would look like?

Answer (score 1):

How do you populate the drop-down? Did you write the names into the dialog, or is there a list of names in the workbook somewhere?

You could:

- insert a column on Sheet2 before column C and enter the names into this column, so they are next to the values they relate to. These values are now in column D.
- use a Vlookup to find the related info with a formula like

`=vlookup(A1,Sheet2!$C$6:$D$20,2,False)`

If you cannot /don't want to put the list of names next to the other info on sheet 2, put the list of names anywhere, say in cells Z1 to Z20 on sheet 1. Then you could use a formula like

```
=index(Sheet2!$C$6:$c$20,match(A1,$Z$1:$Z$20,0))
```

Comment: Well, the drop down has all of the name beneath it immediately. I then hid those rows for cosmetic reasons. I created the drop down using Data Validation. The names do exist on a "Roster" sheet within the workbook. However, the goal, is to only show the data for the name being displayed in the drop down menu.

Comment: So, the roster on Sheet2 has the names in it? Are the names on the left of the roster table? Then you can use the Vlookup formula. If you need more help, edit the question with a better description of your data.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in VBA via event Worksheet_SelectionChange

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
If Selection.Count = 1 Then
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then
    // do a switch statment here, where you assign F34 value
    End If 
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your desired functionality can be achieved without VBA. Let's build the sheet step by step:

We need the value for the dropdown that will show up in A1.
    As you already wrote, there is a sheet (I name it `roster`). 
    Here we enter the value for the dropdown and in the cell right next
    to it the desired address where you want to get the data from:

```
  |  A     |    B      |
  +--------+-----------+
1 | Name_1 | Sheet2!C6 |
2 | Name_2 | Sheet2!C7 |
3 | Name_3 | Sheet2!C8 |
```

Go to Cell `A1` and set the validity to "Allow cell range" and set the cell range to `roster.$A$1:$A$3`. You now have the dropdown.

As the next step, let's enter the value in Sheet2: go to `Sheet2` and enter the value to retrieve (I just use some stupid texts :-) )

```
  | A  | B  |   C   |
  +----+----+-------+
6 |    |    | Alpha |
7 |    |    | Beta  | 
8 |    |    | Gamma |
```

Now for the interesting part: how to display the values depending on your dropdown selection? We use a combination of `Indirect()` and `VLookup()`:

Go to your cell `F34` and enter the formula below:

```
=INDIRECT(VLOOKUP(A1,roster.$A$2:$B$6,2,FALSE()))
```

What's going on?

- The inner part `VLookup()`, searches for the value of `A1` in the
  matrix where we defined the valid vlaues and the addresses for the
  data, takes the second column (the addr) and retrieves it. So if
  you have "Name_2" in the dropdown, this function will return `Sheet2!C7`
- The outer part uses this address via the `Indirect()` function to
  retrieve from this address (who said Excel doesn't know Pointers),
  so you get the text "Beta".

So all we need is a matrix with valid value, the addresses of the data to retrieve and a single formula. Hope that answers your question, though I'm a bit late to the party, if I look at the timestamp. :-)